# Building an ionic 2/cordova app on PhoneGap in production mode

Tags: ios, cordova, angular, ionic-framework, phonegap-build

### CONTEXT

- I am building a Cordova / Ionic 2 application for iOS.
- The application is built on PhoneGap build website to generate the ipa.
- The application is generated successfully and I can launch the application

### PROBLEM

I defined some configurations for development and for production using

`process.env.IONIC_ENV === 'prod'` switch in one of my angular module file. But when i'm running the application, it's clearly running the development configuration.

I also uncompressed and checked the resulting ipa `www/build/main.js` file and went to look for my environment module.

The snippet that was looking for the environment variable which was originally

`useValue: process.env.IONIC_ENV === 'prod' ? ProdEnv : DevEnv`

Had been converted to:

`useValue:  false ? ProdEnv : __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__environment_dev__`

It clearly show me that the preprocessor runned and converted the check into false, which imply that my build is not running with the IONIC_ENV set to 'prod'

### QUESTION

How do I make Phonegap build build my iOS application in production mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhoneGap Build builds each native mobile app using the exact code files you give it - there's no concept of "dev" vs. "prod". Based on the reference to "process.env.IONIC_ENV", I'm guessing you're using [Ionic's App Scripts](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts) to precompile your app. I'm not familiar with them, but based on [the available tasks](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts#all-available-tasks), you'd run: **build --prod** before uploading the code to PhoneGap Build.

PhoneGap Build does [have an API](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/developer-api/), so technically you could "make" Build create your app in production mode by using those scripts plus your own to "build --prod" then upload the app via their API.

Comment: Well I didn't realize that when I was uploading my project it was in fact using the assets i had built on my side. Building using the  build --prod flag did make this a prod build.

Comment: There's a lot of powerful, useful features between Ionic and PG Build, but that also means confusion! I get lost often, myself :)